# AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'myapp.EmailUser' that has not been installed

Tags: python, django

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /
AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'myapp.EmailUser' that has not been installed
```

I have created my models in `myapp/models/` folder.

`EmailUser` class exists in the file `user.py`.

Code in `__init__.py` in models folder:

```
from user import *
```

In myapp `__init__.py` has the code :

```
from models import EmailUser
```

Can someone help me to fix the issue.

When I try to run the django locally with runserver command it is working fine. But when I try to run the same with wsgi I am facing this issue.

Settings.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'



DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'test',  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': 'test',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or           '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',  # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.EmailUser'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Have you added `myapp` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` section of your settings.py?

Comment: your wsgi is showing to wrong settings may be?

Comment: Did you change the name of your project and not update the change in `wsgi.py`?

Comment: Could you include your entire settings.py file? It is possible that your wsgi.py isn't set up correctly and if this is the first included app, it could error.

Comment: I have updated the settings.py and wsgi.py in the question.